# Office 2019 Ribbon too chunky with DPI scaling

Tags: microsoft-office, high-dpi

I've just bought a Dell XPS 15 and a pair of 4k monitors.  I have all 3 screens set to 200% scaling, and when I run an Office app, the buttons on the ribbon have WAY too much margin/padding and cause the ribbon to show a truncated view, despite the fact that I have more than enough room to show the whole thing:

[image]

I can't seem to find a setting anywhere to stop Office from doing this, and even if I set the scaling of all screens to 100%, the ribbon still looks chunkier than it does on my old laptop - could it be an Office 2019 thing?

For reference, this is what it looks like in Office 2016 on my old laptop (also at 200%) - much more compact and the whole ribbon shows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's in Touch Mode and switching to Mouse Mode fixes it.  In order to change the `Touch/Mouse Mode` you must add the button to the toolbar.

[image]

Once the button has been added you can easily switch between each mode.

[image]

Source: [Office 2019 Ribbon icons suddenly appear widely spaced out (all apps except Outlook)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-2019-ribbon-icons-suddenly-appear-widely/c5f3fc96-7387-4ab5-9be1-5e5ff3262537)

Comment: I have made a proposed edit to your answer, in order to include the relevant information in the body of the answer, instead of just having a url that might not work in 60 days.  Please take a moment to verify you agree with the changes, and keep in mind, that answers which only contain a url are not acceptable answers here at Super User.